# python: get file size while writing to .tgz file using tarfile.py

Tags: python-2.7, tarfile

I have to create a compressed archive file (.tgz) which can be limited by a maximum allowed size. Have to use python 2.7 to create the .tgz file, so using the tarfile.py module.

While adding files to the .tgz archive I should check if the maximum allowed size is not exceeded. Can't seem to find a way to determine the size of the .tgz file while it is opened for writing (mode='w|gz').

Is this at all possible? If so how can I manage this? Thanks in advance